# Sort ArrayList<String> by Date excluding the first half of the String

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, date

I'm trying to sort a string which has this format:

```
Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:28/08/2019
```

This is the method I used to sort by the parameter **Eta** which is an Int:

```
Collections.sort(user_list, new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return Comparator.comparing(this::extractInt)
                        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                        .compare(o1, o2);
            }
            private int extractInt(String s) {
                try {
                    return Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[1].trim());
                } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

How can I convert it to sort Date objects assuming that the Date parameter will never be null? I tried to make an extractDate method but then I don't know what to insert where there is `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Comment: Note that your code to sort by `Eta` can be shortened to `Collections.sort(user_list, Comparator.comparingInt(this::extractInt));`, where `extractInt` is a private method declared in the class. Also, though unrelated to this question, [didn't you ask about how to sort by `Eta` before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605015/sort-arrayliststring-excluding-the-digits-on-the-first-half-of-the-string)? Why are you not using the approach suggested by the answers?

Comment: what is `user_list`? Provide complete code

Comment: Also,  `s.split(":")[1]` seems to be the `XX    Genere` part, which is not a valid number.

Comment: As Sweeper mentioned, your code doesn't match what you've described above it. Anyway, searching for "how to parse date" and "sort by date" shouldn't be that hard, right? What is the problem you're facing with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to do it this way:

```
// Creating some dummy data
List<String> userList = Arrays.asList("Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:28/08/2019",
        "Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:26/08/2019",
        "Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:30/08/2019",
        "Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:12/08/2019");

// Sorting based on LocalDate
userList.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> {
    String stringDate = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(':') + 1).trim();
    return LocalDate.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}));

// printing the lists
userList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Sorted Result:**

```
Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:12/08/2019
Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:26/08/2019
Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:28/08/2019
Test: XX    Genere: Maschio    Eta: YY    Protocollo: A    Date:30/08/2019
```